# Why is the button element not displaying next to the input form?

Tags: html, css

I’m having trouble with some basic positioning that I wouldn’t usually encounter. I just want the subscribe button to be 20% wide as it should be and to the left of the input form.

Displaying as a block, inline or inline-block with left floats does nothing, which seems to be the obvious solution.

I’m not sure why but as soon as I added the mail chimp code the input form remains the same but the button displays on the next line below and is wider than it was. I have set the ids and classes to obey the internal stylesheet and not mail chimp’s.

Why is this element not obeying basic styling? Or am I missing something basic?

Appreciate any help, thanks.

```css
#newsletter {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 56%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 0 25px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.f1 {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: darkblue;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.f2 {}

#f-sm,
#f-em {
  padding-top: 15px;
  display: block;
}

#f-em form input {
  margin: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 30px;
  background: pink;
  float: left;
}

#newsletter-button {
  width: 20%;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="newsletter">
  <span class="f1">Newsletter Signup</span>
  <span class="f2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare...</span>
  <span id="f-em">
<form action="action_here" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
<input type="email" placeholder="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
<div id="mce-responses">
<div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="newsletter-button">
</form>
</span>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need more specificity added to the custom style rules you've declared, e.g: `#f-em form #newsletter-button`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule `#f-em form input` is applying to both button and input. Giving both 80% width.

Both your button (`<input type="submit" ...>`) and your text field (`<input type="text">`) match your rule `#f-em` form input which has `width:80%.`

Your button also matches your `#newsletter-button` rule but this is less specific than the above rule so gets over overridden.

Answer (score 1):

This rule `#f-em form input` in your css is abit not specific its applying to all the input tag elements and still the form and also the #f-em. You can  try and make it more specific.

For aligning the button to the left of the form you can try the below code to align it.

```
    form { 
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 30px;
    background: pink;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    input{ 
    float:left; 
    width:20%;
    }
```